# How to convert two 4-bit chunk into 1 byte in Dart?

Tags: dart, binary, typeconverter

```
byte 0: min_value (0-3 bit)
        max_value (4-7 bit)
```

The `byte0` should be the min and max values combined.

min and max values are both integers (in 0-15 range).
I should convert them into 4-bit binary, and combine them somehow? (how?)

E.g.

```
min_value=2  // 0010
max_value=3  // 0011
```

The result should be an `Uint8`, and the value: `00100011`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [shift left operator `<<`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/int/operator_shift_left.html) to get the result you want:

```
result = ((min_value << 4) + max_value).toRadixString(2).padLeft(8, '0');
```

Comment: I don't understand.

I get the `2` and `3` decimal numbers from an input, how can I get `00100011` in the end?

Comment: The question was not clear about what you wanted as result. I updated the answer.